# Programa parando de funcionar em C

Tags: c, syntax-error

Olá, eu estou tendo um problema com um código meu em C. É um trabalho para faculdade e o código é simples, é um script pra receber dados (usuários e produtos), vender os produtos e listar os clientes existentes, eu fiz a parte de cadastro de usuário e produtos normalmente, porém na parte de pesquisar se um usuário já existe está dando um erro, ele simplesmente dá "o programa parou de responder".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char nomeCliente[100][50];
int cpf[50][30];

char descricaoProduto[20][30];
int valorDeVenda[50];

int i;

int menu;

void cadastroClientes();
void cadastroProduto();
void venderProdutos();

int main()
{
    printf("1 - Cadastrar usuário");
    printf("\n2 - Cadastrar produto\n");
    printf("3 - Vender Produtos\n");
    printf("4-Relatorios\n");
    printf("\nOpção a ser acessada: ");
    scanf("%d", &menu);

    switch (menu)
    {
    case 1:
        cadastroClientes();
        break;
    case 2:
        cadastroProduto();
        break;
    case 3:
        venderProdutos();
        break;
    }
}

void cadastroClientes()
{
    static int linha;
    do
    {

        printf("\nNome: \n");
        scanf("%s", &nomeCliente[i]);
        printf("\n CPF: ");
        scanf("%s", &cpf);
        printf("\ndigite 1 para fazer outro cadastro ou outro valor para voltar ao menu ");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        if (menu != 1)
        {
            main();
        }
        linha++;
    } while (menu == 1);
}

void cadastroProduto()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\n nome do produto: ");
        scanf("%s", &descricaoProduto);
        printf("\npreço de venda ");
        scanf("%s", &valorDeVenda);
        printf("\n digite 2 para fazer outro cadastro de produto ou outro número para voltar ao menu ");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        if (menu != 2)
        {
            main();
        }
    } while (menu == 2);
}

void venderProdutos()
{

    char cliente;

    printf("digite o nome do cliente: ");
    scanf("%c", &cliente);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(nomeCliente[i], cliente) == 0)
        {
            printf("encontrou");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("erro");
        }
    }
}
```

o erro está em algum lugar na função "venderProdutos()", especificamente no strcmp. eu testei a comparação entre o "nomeCliente, "a")" e deu certo, então creio que seja algum problema no índice ou algo assim.

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou a variável `cliente` como tipo `char`.

Isso significa que ela irá armazenar um único caractere, sem sequer ser seguido por um *null terminator*, como as strings em C.

Tente declara-lo como um array de caracteres de tamanho 50 (mesmo tamanho que você está armazenando no `nomeCliente`) e então faça o `scanf` utilizando `%s` para ler uma string, ou utilize `%49s` para se certificar que a entrada não irá estourar o tamanho do seu array.

```
int venderProdutos()
{
    char cliente[50];

    printf("digite o nome do cliente: ");
    scanf("%49s", cliente);

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(nomeCliente[i], cliente) == 0)
        {
            printf("encontrou");
            return i;
        }
    }

    printf("erro");
    return -1;
}
```

Também seria bom receber quantos clientes você tem populado no array de `nomeCliente` na função, dessa forma você só percorreria esse número ao invés de percorrer todas as 100 posições, afinal, não sabemos nem se todas as 100 posições estão preenchidas.

Comment: muito obrigado mano, era isso mesmo

Comment: se puder me ajudar com outro probleminha que to enfrentando, agradeço...
eu tenho também que listar vários tipos de dados, eu to fazendo isso usando o seguinte trecho de código: "int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", nomeCliente[i]);
    }"

porém o "erro" tá que ele tá mostrando 100 resultados, que é o tamanho que coloquei ali, porém eu quero que seja mostrado apenas os clientes existentes, se houver só 1, só poderá mostrar 1 e assim por diante, do modo que fiz ele está mostrando sempre 100 resultados, e quando não há nenhum cliente ele mostra 100 (nulls)

Comment: agora que percebi que é isso mesmo que você tinha dito ali embaixo, porém mantenho a pergunta porque não sei bem como eu faria isso do jeito que você disse

Comment: C não mantém a contagem de quantos itens do array estão populados, você tem que declarar uma variável para manter essa contagem. Inclusive parece que você já declarou a variável `linha` (a qual você deveria inicializa-la com 0). Apena use ela como delimitador `for (i = 0; i < linha; i++)`